# intellij won't start after switch boot jdk

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I wanted to debug my project under Open JDK 11, so I tried to switch boot jdk to the OpenJDK11 path. I am using the community version on Windows 10.
The suggested restart didn't happen, I only got the following error:
[JDK needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSLmM.png)

How can I reset the boot jdk without Intellij starting?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Answer (score 2):

The IntelliJ [Advanced Configuration docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html) say the configuration directory on windows is:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> %HOMEPATH%\.<product><version>\config
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JohnS\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\config
> ```

Then, just delete the `studio.jdk` file in that directory, and IntelliJ will boot with its default.

I have a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58681072/9636) about Android Studio

Comment: I removed a file called `idea64.exe.jdk` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS(checked on Catalina) just run the "**repair**" binary located in:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just delete this config file /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1/idea.jdk

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful scripts that will be shipped along with intelliJ which will help in investigate the IntelliJ issues.
The location of shell scripts

> /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin

1. repair.sh - This will repair any issues with the plugins or the local setup
2. printenv.sh - This will print the env variables, like all the classpaths etc
3. inspect.sh - This script helped me resolve the issue. It printed all the vmoptions config files that IntelliJ is looking for. And I found the idea.jdk file where unsupported version if Java is set.

> /Users/xxxx/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/idea.jdk

And below error

```
2023-10-17 06:02:00.465 idea[13548:138982] Main class com/intellij/idea/Main not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/intellij/idea/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1114)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.consumeClassData(UrlClassLoader.java:268)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ZipResourceFile.findClass(ZipResourceFile.java:113)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.findClass(JarLoader.java:58)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassInLoader(ClassPath.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassWithoutCache(ClassPath.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClass(ClassPath.java:210)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:218)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
```

I remove this file and restarted it. It worked like a charm.