# How do I run Android Studio with a newer JRE or JDK on the mac?

Tags: java, macos, android-studio

I’m trying to run Android Studio with JDK 13 just because I feel like it must run faster than the JDK 8 that comes embedded with it.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) (which I found from [`umang shukla`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326632/9636)), we can force Android Studio to use something other than the embedded JDK by setting `STUDIO_JDK`.

> **STUDIO_JDK**
>
> Sets the location of the JDK with which to run Studio. When you launch Android Studio, it checks the `STUDIO_JDK`,
>   `JDK_HOME`, and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables in that order.

And I did that:

```
$ export STUDIO_JDK=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 13`
$ echo $STUDIO_JDK
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
$ open /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/
$ ps ax | grep Android
 1198   ??  R      1:07.86 /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
 1269   ??  S      0:00.02 /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier
 1300 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep Android
$ ps eww 1198
 PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
 1198   ??  S      1:46.13 /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ANDROID_HOME=/Users/hborders/Library/Android/sdk TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home TMPDIR=/var/folders/r6/qtc_vgrx1xb2gqsg08y0tl000000gp/T/ __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0x0:0x0 SHELL=/bin/bash _=/usr/bin/open HOME=/Users/hborders TERM_SESSION_ID=CA1F90D5-ABE9-427A-ACC5-EEE63AC66CAB SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.J9ll4GUN4M/Listeners Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.B3Rds8GPV9/Render TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.2 SHLVL=1 PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/hborders/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/hborders/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin:/Users/hborders/go/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4O8kDH9XQS/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 TERM=xterm-256color LOGNAME=hborders XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.google.android.studio.55476 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec GOPATH=/Users/hborders/go USER=hborders XPC_FLAGS=0x1 STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home PWD=/Users/hborders
```

However, when I look in Android Studio’s Collect Troubleshooting Information dialog, I get the following information:

```
Build version: Android Studio 3.5.1 Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203 September 25, 2019
Java version: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405x86_64
Operating System: Mac OS X (10.14.6, x86_64)
JVM version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JetBrains s.r.o
```

I also tried launching Android Studio thusly:

```
$ /Applications/Android Studio 3.5.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

And I got the same result. [I filed an Android Studio issue about this. Please star it.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143804930)

Any ideas?

Comment: out of curiosity, what gives you the feeling that "it must run faster than JDK 8"?

Comment: there is little advance, because the target devices will only execute Java 6, 7 or 8 byte-code. getting a new computer might rather run it faster, than attempting to run a later JDK.

Comment: @MartinZeitler is there really an advantage of running any Java IDE on newer version?
The compiled code targets the defined version, so for the written progam it doesn't makes a difference. The JRE runs the byte code, newer JRE/JDK version means the byte code can use a bit different structures/procedures, but if the program (in our case IDE) is targeted to use version X, then the advantages of X+1 shouldn't be used. Dropping it all, we still end up in a point were the Java programs depends on the implementations of JDK/JRE for a particular platform.

Comment: @itwasntme source/target compatibility mode can be set for `javaCompile` tasks, while JDK 8 might currently be the recommend one; Android Studio only supports a sub-set of Java 8 features, see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: @MartinZeitler (have read) I don't think this answers my question. The already compiled program which targets the version X, won't take any advantage if ran on version X+1 (or +2, just a sample). And here the question is not about the program/app being written but the IDE itself, so as you've said only "new computer might rather run it faster".

Comment: I don't think JDK 13 will have any affect on the speed of my Android applications that I make with Android Studio. I do think that JDK 13 will run Android Studio itself faster than JDK 8 because JDK 13 will certainly have a better native JIT compiler and garbage collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

Don't try to do this. Android Studio 3.5.1 hangs when trying to change the `boot jdk`. [I filed this in the Android Studio issue tracker. Please star it.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143824143)

Someone privately suggested:

`cmd+shift+a` -> `switch boot jdk`

This definitely changed Android Studio's behavior. However, Android Studio `3.5.1` hung at the splash screen.

[image: Android Studio splash screen hangs with different boot jdk]

This happened when I tried to start it with either Oracle `JDK 13`:

```
java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

or Oracle `JDK 11`:

```
java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

To fix this problem, I found that Android Studio stores the `boot jdk` preference in [`~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>` on macOS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) (`~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.5` in my case).

Then, I simply deleted the `studio.jdk` file, and Android Studio started normally again.

Comment: FWIW, the first time I tried exactly this, I had exactly the same results: boot hung at splash screen.  I just tried it again (AS 3.6 font rendering is horrible) and it worked!  AS is now running on a standard Java and the font rendering is correct.

Comment: So it started working with Android Studio 3.6? If so, please consider commenting on my google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143824143

Comment: Sadly, nothing like that.  3.6 hung at the boot screen just as you describe.  I got rid of the `studio.jdk` file just as you described.  Quite accidentally, I ran the boot switcher again, (about a week later) and it worked.  I have no idea what happened in between that changed things.

Comment: This still happens on 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

[Jetbrains has instructions for choosing the underlying runtime.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

At a high level:

Install the [Choose Runtime plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12836-choose-runtime)

Then do "Find Action" in the IDE and select "Choose Runtime"

Comment: Yes it does!  On the other hand, as @Heath points out, following those instructions will cause AS to hang at the splash screen...